# How to navigate between panorama page and a new page (non panorama)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

So i've got listitems, when i click on an item, i have to navigate to a new page (non panorama). Like the standard databound application. I have copy paste the code like a databound application, doesn't do what I want.

Here is my xaml of panorama page.

```
<controls:PanoramaItem x:Name="deeln" Header="Deelnemers" Style="{StaticResource subtitle}">
                <!--Double line list with image placeholder and text wrapping-->
                <ListBox Margin="12,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsDeelnemer}" x:Name="lbDeelnemer" SelectionChanged="lbDeelnemer_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LineNr}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="35" ></TextBlock>
                                    <StackPanel Width="430" Height="100">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LineNaamWielrenner1}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="35"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LineNaamWielrenner2}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="35"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Here is my code of the panorama page.

```
private void lbDeelnemer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            #region go to specific deelnemerinfo screen

           // int indexer = lbDeelnemer.SelectedIndex;

            // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
            if (lbDeelnemer.SelectedIndex == -1)
                return;
            // Navigate to the new page                    
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DeelnemerInfo.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DeelnemerInfo.xaml?selectedItem=" + lbDeelnemer.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
            // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
            lbDeelnemer.SelectedIndex = -1;

            #endregion
        }
```

Note: /DeelnemerInfo.xaml is the new page (non panorama page) just a basic portrait page.
Help me!

Comment: You want to pass parameters to a new page, I'm sorry, but I did not understand what the problem is?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in lbDeelnemer_SelectionChanged, does it get raised? What actually happens when you change selection in the listbox?

Comment: No It didn't raised, i checked that already but don't know how to fix..

Comment: @Alexandr I just want to navigate, no params.

Comment: So in general that's my problem that if I click on a listitem it doesn't react my selectionchanged, it's always -1 as index i get back.

Comment: And like you say @igrali my selectionchanged event doesn't raise. What could it be? I tried so hard already..

Comment: I fixed it myself! :-D The problem was my controls in xaml of my Main, I removed de scrollviewer and the second stackpanel. It works know..strange thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ScrollViewer from your list.

The ScrollViewer captures the taps/clicks and doesn't let the ListBox get them (and thus the ListBox does not get the event).

You can see the same thing happening when you have a button inside a ListBox - Selection will not change when the button is tapped.

Comment: I just fixed that already and it works but know i can't scroll because the scrollviewer is gone. How do I fix that? @Shahar Prish

Comment: You want to navigate within each item?

Comment: So i've got 24 listitems, no I removed the scrollviewer for my previous problem. Now I want still able to scroll vertically. But I can add a scrollviewer because my previous problem will be back. Do you understand it know? @Shahar Prish

Comment: Nope. You want to scroll the entire list-box, or each individual item inside the list?

Comment: each individual item in the list

Comment: Ah. So that's not really possible. Also - think of your users... The only way this will be a passing user experience (and even then, it will be pretty bad) is if as you scroll each item, and it reaches the "bottom" of the item, the list will start scrolling. Take a look at other apps on Windows Phone, this is not really done in any app I've seen. (Not possible = without significant effort on customizing the controls or writing them yourself)

Comment: Lol, it's possible. Just added this to my listbox and everything works fine. ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto". You may like it if you want. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: If you really want understand my problem I want something like the databound application scroll. You don't understand my problem at all I think.

Comment: Oh. You want HORIZONTAL scrolling? It could very well be that I don't understand the problem. Sorry. :)